# How to get link for Dropbox file for downloading in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, dropbox-api

Dropbox API v2 allows to get temporary link for downloading of file by end point:

/get_temporary_link

This link allows to download file in Firefox and Chrome but does not in IE11. For unknown reason IE11 does not download file from this link, for example by setting src of iframe to this link.

There is also endpoint: /download. It allows to download file in IE but response header "content-disposition" contains incorrect file name: unspecified. Therefore this link is not convenient for user 
for downloading in browser.

From the other side for downloading of file the Dropbox site uses link in form

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/....

It allows to download file in IE and header "content-disposition" contains correct file name.

Is there way to get link for downloading in form

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/....

Comment: Using the [/2/files/get_temporary_link](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_temporary_link) endpoint is the right way to get a link to a file like this. There is unfortunately a known issue with these links in IE 11 in particular, but I don't have a timeline for a fix.

Comment: We have the same problem. There is a thread about it on the Dropbox support forum here: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/Using-resulting-link-from-get-temporary-link-in-IE-new-window/td-p/194218
Our temporary solution was to get an extension for access to API v1 until this is solved.

Comment: The issue noted in my earlier comment is fixed now.